# Is there a way to deactivate IIS integration in Net Core 3.X app without having to reproduce the code from CreateDefaultBuilder

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel

In version 3.0 and up of Net Core a web application can be setup this way:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
            {
                var settingsFile = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APP_SETTINGS");
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(settingsFile))
                {
                    config.AddJsonFile(settingsFile, optional: false);
                }
            });
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

While using `CreateDefaultBuilder` very convenient and abstracts a lot of boilerplate, it also forcibly enables IIS integrations for the app. In my case, I want to run the app using raw Kestrel without IIS proxying requests.

Is my only choice to extract all the boilerplate from `CreateDefaultBuilder()` if I want to not use the IIS integrations, or can I somehow overwrite this? I've been studying the source code for this methods and I can't see a way to solve this.

Do you know of an easier method to achieve this other than having to write all the setup code myself?